# Uncaught referenceError: showTechnical is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add tabs so when they are clicked, it shows different content.  However, I am getting 3 console errors.  Two are on load, and the 3rd is every time the technical link is clicked.
The two that present on page load are:

```
Uncaught Syntaxerror: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getcontext' of null
Uncaught referenceError: showTechnical is not defined
```

---

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showTechnical()
{
document.getElementById('container123').value='
<div class="row" id="technical">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=settlement" />Settlement</div><div     class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=tickets" />Tickets</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=c_tickets" />Complimentary    Tickets</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=texes" />Texes</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=p_l_m" />Permits/Licenses/Certificates</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=merchandise" />Merchandise</div>   <div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=special_regs" />Special   Regulations</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=control_production" />Control of Production</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=duration_performance" />Duration Performance</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=support_talent" />Support Talent</div>    </div>


<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=prod_office" />Production Office</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=dress_rooms" />Dressing Rooms</div>  <div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=runner" />Runner</div><div   class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=stage_size" />Stage Size</div><div  class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=house_blacks" />House Blacks</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=barricade" />Barricade</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=foh_mix_position" />FOH Mix Position</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=dj_riser" />DJ Riser</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=dj_equip" />DJ Equipment</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=stagehands" />Stagehands</div>       </div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=foh_speaker_system" />FOH Speaker System</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=foh_console" />FOH Console</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=foh_effects" />FOH Effects</div>  <div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=communication" />Communication</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=monitor_system" />Monitor System</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=monitor_wedges" />Monitor Wedges</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=wireless_mic" />Wireless  Microphones</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=lighting_req" />Lighting  Requirements</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=video_req" />Video  Requirements</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=ground_transportation" />Ground Transportation</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=security_req" />Security    Requirements</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=towels" />Towels</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=purchasers_p_r" />Purchasers  Production Representative</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=equipment_placement" />Equipment Placement</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=sound_checks" />Sound Checks</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=power_req" />Power Requirements</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=parking" />Parking</div><div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="technical[]" value=tour_bus_power" />Tour Bus Power</div>    <input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next">    </div>
</div>';
};
</script>
```

Then, I call the div a couple lines down:

```
<div id="container123">
<li><a href="#" onclick="showTechnical()">Technical</a></li>
```

Comment: `divs` don't have `value` and multiline strings don't work like that in JavaScript, you have to concatenate. You want `innerHTML`.

Comment: either use `.html` or `.append` method as per need

Comment: Or create your HTML in HTML and toggle your div on and off.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `innerHTML` or in jQuery, `.html()`

Unfortunately, you can't multiline JS strings like that, which is also breaking your code.

You either have to:

- add a trailing `\` for every line. But that's just tedious.

  ```
  var string = "Some \
                multiline \
                string";
  ```
- or do everything in 1 line. But that's just messy.
- or place the "template" you have in a `<script>` whose type is **not** `text/javascript` which prevents it from being parsed. ID it and get the contents using innerHTML. Much cleaner.

  ```
  <script type="text/template" id="myTemplate">
    HTML in here
  </script>
  ```

  You can retrieve them using

  ```
  var contents = document.getElementById('myTemplate').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('container123').innerHTML = contents;
  ```

  Or in jQuery

  ```
  var contents = $('#myTemplate');
  $('#container123').html(contents);
  ```

Comment: `document.getElementById('container123').value`? does div supports value?..cant it be `.html()` or '.value()'

Comment: @captain Just updated it. I thought the OP wanted to edit HTML in a textarea or something.